# Update Facebook status issue(Java)

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-java-api

I m trying simple program to update FB status, but its giving me error, 
This is what i m trying ...

```
public class SendtoFacebook {

public static void main(String a[]) throws FacebookException {

    SendtoFacebook sfb = new SendtoFacebook();
    sfb.send("From My App: Rohan's App");
}

public void send(String message) throws FacebookException {

    String FB_APP_API_KEY = new String("461632878708096");
    String FB_APP_SECRET = new String("5513aa2b99879879897ff0fa5a7a");
    String FB_SESSION_KEY = "";
    FacebookJsonRestClient facebook = new FacebookJsonRestClient(FB_APP_API_KEY, FB_APP_SECRET);

    //FacebookJsonRestClient facebookClient2 = (FacebookJsonRestClient)facebook.getFacebookRestClient();
    FacebookJsonRestClient facebookClient = (FacebookJsonRestClient) facebook;
    facebookClient.stream_publish(message, null, null, null, null);

    System.out.println("successfully updated");

}
```

}

And m getting this error_
    Exception in thread "main" com.google.code.facebookapi.FacebookException: parameters uid or session key required
    at com.google.code.facebookapi.JsonHelper.parseCallResult(JsonHelper.java:59)
    at com.google.code.facebookapi.ExtensibleClient.extractString(ExtensibleClient.java:2296)
    at com.google.code.facebookapi.ExtensibleClient.stream_publish(ExtensibleClient.java:2150)
    at com.google.code.facebookapi.SpecificReturnTypeAdapter.stream_publish(SpecificReturnTypeAdapter.java:503)
    at socialdemo.SendtoFacebook.send(SendtoFacebook.java:31)
    at socialdemo.SendtoFacebook.main(SendtoFacebook.java:19)

Is any buddy knw about this?
plz.. n thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook APIs require the session key. When I need such a key, I go to [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), click on "Get Access Token", select the required authentications from the lists, and use the generated session key in my program. It expires after a day or so, in which case I re-generate one.

Hope that helps.

Regards,

Salil

Comment: select the required authentications from the lists ? from which list
I have Access Token, then what next?

Comment: Select "Get Access Token". This will give you a popup showing several user/friends/extended permissions you can choose from. Tick the required options and select "Get Access Token" in the bottom. The API page will ask you for permission to get the information from your facebook account. Once you grant it, you will see the new access token in the "Access Token:" on the original page.

Then use that token (key) in your program for variable `FB_APP_API_KEY`.

Comment: its giving me error _  
Exception in thread "main" _com.google.code.facebookapi.FacebookException: Session key is malformed._

Comment: Which permission did you take? Did you check the Extended permissions?